# How to retrieve Medium stories for a user from the API?

Tags: medium.com-publishing-api

I'm trying to integrate Medium blogging into an app by showing some cards with posts images and links to the original Medium publication.

From Medium API docs I can see how to retrieve publications and create posts, but it doesn't mention retrieving posts. Is retrieving posts/stories for a user currently possible using the Medium's API?

Comment: does not seem possible for now. Apparently you can only list publications and add a post to a publication. (but you can't even change a post after you created it, and the POST endpoint does not return a Location header with the url to the newly created post.)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The API is write-only and is not intended to retrieve posts (Medium staff told me)

You can simply use the RSS feed as such:

```
https://medium.com/feed/@your_profile
```

You can simply get the RSS feed via GET, then if you need it in JSON format just use a NPM module like [rss-to-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss-to-json) and you're good to go.

Comment: I made a microservice wrapper for the rss-to-json package Antonio was mentioning above that also makes it easy to pull that data down: https://clay.run/services/nicoslepicos/rss-to-json. If you wanted to parameterize it so the endpoint always just pulls down some specific feed, just fork this endpoint with `clay fork nicoslepicos/rss-to-json` and then  just put in the hardcoded feed you want it to always return.

Alternatively, there's this other microservice: https://clay.run/services/nicoslepicos/medium-get-users-posts, which uses the Medium RSS feed specifically.

Comment: Is it possible to get medium's front page stories with RSS or something?

Comment: not all the medium posts from an author show in the feed

Comment: How to get the next page of a medium feed?

Comment: Btw, I create a project that you can embed medium articles into your Readme. Check it out: https://github.com/tonynguyenit18/github-readme-social-article

Comment: SOmeone knows how to get older psots from medium programaticvally. The feed only shows the last ten posts but not older posts.

Comment: Lord Why. Won't. XML. Just. Die?

Comment: @RonnieRoyston I feel your pain, lol

Comment: @RonnieRoyston et. al, check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78014795/10237506) below. It solves this question now with modern approach, is completely free and open source, and best of all doesn't require messing around with XML :-)

Answer (score 13):

Edit:

It is possible to make a request to the following URL and you will get the response. Unfortunately, the response is in RSS format which would require some parsing to JSON if needed.

```
https://medium.com/feed/@yourhandle
```

**⚠️ The following approach is not applicable anymore as it is behind Cloudflare's DDoS protection.**

If you planning to get it from the Client-side using JavaScript or jQuery or Angular, etc. then you need to build an API gateway or web service that serves your feed. In the case of PHP, RoR, or any server-side that should not be the case.

You can get it directly in JSON format as given beneath:

```
https://medium.com/@yourhandle/latest?format=json
```

In my case, I made a simple web service in the express app and host it over Heroku. React App hits the API exposed over Heroku and gets the data.

```
const MEDIUM_URL = "https://medium.com/@yourhandle/latest?format=json";

router.get("/posts", (req, res, next) => {
  request.get(MEDIUM_URL, (err, apiRes, body) => {
    if (!err && apiRes.statusCode === 200) {
      let i = body.indexOf("{");
      const data = body.substr(i);
      res.send(data);
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(500).json(err);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: is there a way to get the single post content?

Comment: This is no longer valid. Cloudflare is adding a captcha challenge unfortunately.

Comment: Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78014795/10237506) below. It solves this question now with modern approach, is completely free and open source, and best of all doesn't require messing around with XML :-)

Answer (score 11):

Nowadays this URL:

```
https://medium.com/@username/latest?format=json
```

sits behind Cloudflare's DDoS protection service so instead of consistently being served your feed in JSON format, you will usually receive instead an HTML which is suppose to render a website to complete a reCAPTCHA and leaving you with no data from an API request.

And the following:

```
https://medium.com/feed/@username
```

has a limit of the latest 10 posts.

I'd suggest [this free Cloudflare Worker](https://github.com/alekrumkamp/medium-feed-json) that I made for this purpose. It works as a facade so you don't have to worry about neither how the posts are obtained from source, reCAPTCHAs or pagination.

[Full article](https://medium.com/@alekrumkamp/how-to-fetch-your-medium-feed-in-17ms-using-cloudflare-workers-63a9c49c6c19) about it.

[Live example](https://medium-feed.alekrumkamp.workers.dev/). To fetch the following items add the query param `?next=` with the value of the JSON field `next` which the API provides.

Comment: I was using your solution, but I think they recently modified something on their end that made the solution not work anymore :(

Comment: `https://medium.com/feed/@username` also includes data of comments I have made on my own or other stories. So separating them from actual stories is not possible it seems

Comment: Feel free to check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78014795/10237506) below. It solves this question now with modern approach, is completely free and open source, and best of all doesn't require messing around with XML :-)

Answer (score 10):

To get your posts as JSON objects

you can replace your user name instead of @USERNAME.

`https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https://medium.com/feed/@USERNAME`

Answer (score 9):

```
const MdFetch = async (name) => {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https://medium.com/feed/${name}`
  );
  return await res.json();
};
```

> const data = await MdFetch('@chawki726');

Answer (score 5):

With that REST method you would do this: `GET https://api.medium.com/v1/users/{{userId}}/publications` and this would return the title, image, and the item's URL. 
Further details: https://github.com/Medium/medium-api-docs#32-publications .

You can also add "?format=json" to the end of any URL on Medium and get useful data back.

Comment: it's tricky but when they say "publications" they don't mean "user's posts". As Antonio says the only way to access user's posts is through RSS. [See this issue](https://github.com/Medium/medium-api-docs/issues/51)

Answer (score 4):

Use this url, this url will give json format of posts
Replace studytact with your feed name

https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https://medium.com/feed/studytact

Answer (score 2):

I have built a basic function using AWS Lambda and AWS API Gateway if anyone is interested. A detailed explanation is found on [this blog post here](https://medium.com/@markfasel/building-a-basic-web-service-to-display-your-medium-blog-posts-on-your-website-using-aws-api-48597b1771c5) and the repository for the the Lambda function built with Node.js is found here on [Github](https://github.com/markfasel/medium-nodejs-lambda). Hopefully someone here finds it useful.

Comment: Wrapped that AWS Lambda you created into a Clay microservice. Also, as a heads up tried to send you an email to tell you about it but looks like the email on your site is bouncing back :)

Answer (score 1):

(Updating the JS Fiddle and the Clay function that explains it as we updated the function syntax to be cleaner)

I wrapped the Github package @mark-fasel was mentioning below into a Clay microservice that enables you to do exactly this:

Simplified Return Format: https://www.clay.run/services/nicoslepicos/medium-get-user-posts-new/code

I put together a little fiddle, since a user was asking how to use the endpoint in HTML to get the titles for their last 3 posts: 
https://jsfiddle.net/h405m3ma/3/

You can call the API as:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"nicolaerusan"}' https://clay.run/services/nicoslepicos/medium-get-users-posts-simple
```

You can also use it easily in your node code using the clay-client npm package and just write:

```
Clay.run('nicoslepicos/medium-get-user-posts-new', {"profile":"profileValue"})
.then((result) => {

  // Do what you want with returned result
  console.log(result);

})
.catch((error) => {

  console.log(error);

});
```

Hope that's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

## Check this One you will get all info about your own post........

```
mediumController.getBlogs = (req, res) => {
    parser('https://medium.com/feed/@profileName', function (err, rss) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }

        var stories = [];

        for (var i = rss.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            var new_story = {};

            new_story.title = rss[i].title;
            new_story.description = rss[i].description;
            new_story.date = rss[i].date;
            new_story.link = rss[i].link;
            new_story.author = rss[i].author;
            new_story.comments = rss[i].comments;

            stories.push(new_story);
        }
        console.log('stories:');
        console.dir(stories);
        res.json(200, {
            Data: stories
        })
    });

}
```

Comment: what is mediumController, even?

Comment: NodeJs Controller, I guess.
As I see syntax is of NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a custom REST API to retrieve the stats of a given post on Medium, all you need is to send a GET request to my custom API and you will retrieve the stats as a Json abject as follows:
Request :

```
curl https://endpoint/api/stats?story_url=THE_URL_OF_THE_MEDIUM_STORY
```

Response:

```
{
   "claps": 78,
   "comments": 1
}
```

The API responds within a reasonable response time (< 2 sec), you can find more about it [in the following Medium article.](https://mecheri-akram.medium.com/the-missing-part-of-mediums-rest-api-5d377e02d5d9)

Answer (score 0):

It is now **2024**, and I have recently published an NPM package [`medium-sdk-ts`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/medium-sdk-ts) -- my first ever library package!

It supports modern TypeScript and ESM syntax as well as older CommonJS as well.

The package supports fetching **all published posts** for a given **user**, and the best of all is that:

- It handles pagination automatically.
- It is ***completely FREE***.
- It is ***Open Sourced*** [on GitHub](https://github.com/rnag/medium-sdk-ts).
- No access token or authentication is required.

---

If curious, here is the Medium post I have written on it:

https://medium.com/@ritviknag/medium-api-with-javascript-in-2024-2e73440c7fa0

This other Medium post was the inspiration for my approach to **Get the Published Posts of a User** -- using GraphQL:

https://medium.com/@mike820324/web-crawler-getting-medium-post-a6e52fd36fd6

### Usage

Install with `npm` or a package manager of choice:

```
npm i medium-sdk-ts
```

Then, to retrieve all public posts for a user:

```js
import { MediumClient } from 'medium-sdk-ts';

// Access Token is optional, can also be set
// as environment variable `MEDIUM_ACCESS_TOKEN`
const medium = new MediumClient('YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN');

// Get User's Published Posts (Title Only)
const posts = await medium.getPosts('@username');
console.log(`User Posts: ${JSON.stringify(posts, null, 2)}`);
```

### The Problem with Existing Answers

Regarding RSS Feed:

```
https://medium.com/feed/@username
```

This works, but there is a limit and it only returns a user's **10 most recent posts**.

```
https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https://medium.com/feed/@USERNAME
```

Again, the above is a blatant *copy-paste* of `https://medium.com/feed/@username` approach. It just achieves the same end, and is limited to max of 10 posts.

```
https://api.medium.com/v1/users/{{userId}}/publications
```

The above answer totally miss the mark, unfortunately, It returns a user's *publications* which are different from their *posts*.

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"nicolaerusan"}' https://clay.run/services/nicoslepicos/medium-get-users-posts-simple
```

Answers such as above were written a long time back. Most of them do not any longer work. For example the above link to `clay.run` - it leads to an API or page that doesn't exist anymore. Further, other solutions out there are *not free* and will require a *subscription tier*.

In short, the solution as I have outlined above works, and is completely **Free** and [**Open Sourced on GitHub**](https://github.com/rnag/medium-sdk-ts).