# Retrieve posts of a user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, medium.com-publishing-api

How does one retrieve the posts of a user using Medium API?

The documentation shows a `POST` endpoint to create a blog post but a `GET` request to the corresponding endpoint results in an error.

Answer (score 4):

You get the posts of a user by using the RSS feed:

```
https://medium.com/feed/@user_name
```

> Retrieving a user's or publication posts is not possible using the Medium API v1 (current). Medium staff told me it's deliberately write-only. A few things can be listed, like contributors and publications, but not posts and their content. The RSS feed is to be used in this case.

For example, a popular profile:

```
https://medium.com/feed/@vanschneider
```

You can also use it with publications:

```
https://medium.com/feed/desk-of-van-schneider
```

Here is an example using Express and the [parse-rss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-rss) NPM module:

```
var parser = require('parse-rss');

router.get('/blog', function(req, res, next) {

    parser('https://medium.com/feed/@vanschneider', function(err, rss)
    {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }

        var stories = [];

        for (var i = rss.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            var new_story = {};

            new_story.title = rss[i].title;
            new_story.description = rss[i].description;
            new_story.date = rss[i].date;
            new_story.link = rss[i].link;
            new_story.author = rss[i].author;
            new_story.comments = rss[i].comments;

            stories.push(new_story);
        }

        console.log('stories:');
        console.dir(stories);

        res.render('somepage',
        {
            stories: stories,
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Its work great for post content but its not get the image url.Can i get the img url.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not possible to enumerate the list of existing drafts or published posts, e.g. to crosspost to another service or backup your posts to a local archive.

BUT! https://github.com/lambtron/medium-cli
you can lookup for solution here :3

Comment: I used it just to read medium few times. Just for fun.
You can try if you installed medium-cli "medium top 10". But to select article to read you should use arrow keys.

Answer (score 0):

Answered this question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36097527/how-to-retrieve-medium-stories-for-a-user-from-the-api/42635984#42635984). Summary below:

I created a Clay microservice that enables you to do exactly this:

https://clay.run/services/nicoslepicos/medium-get-users-posts

You can call the API as:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"nicolaerusan"}' https://clay.run/services/nicoslepicos/medium-get-users-posts
```

You can also use it easily in your node code using the clay-client npm package and just write:

```
Clay.run('nicoslepicos/medium-get-users-posts', {"username":"usernameValue"})
.then((result) => {

  // Do what you want with returned result
  console.log(result);

})
```

Hope that's helpful!